# Сравнение 2-ух списков в python и последующий вывод с заменой значения

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется задача: сравнить два списка. Если элемент первого списка равен элементу второго списка, то выводится 1, если не равен, то выводится 1.

```
a = ["тест" , "услуга2" , "задание" , "услуга4" , "тест5" , "тест6" , "тест7" , "услуга8" , "группа"]
b = ["тест6" , "услуга2" , "услуга4" , "услуга8"]

common = list(set(a) & set(b))

for i in a:
    if common:
        print(1)
    else:
        print(0)
```

В конечном итоге выводит только единицы. В чем проблема?

Comment: *если элемент первого списка равен элементу второго списка* - просто присутствует во втором или на той же позиции?

Comment: как минимум `if i in common:`

Comment: Сравнение никак не учитывает сравниваемый элемент, а `if common` всегда true

Comment: У вас из условия задачи 1 выводится всегда, если равен или не равен. "Если элемент первого списка равен элементу второго списка, то выводится 1, если не равен, то выводится 1."

Comment: просто присутствует во втором

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как насчёт такого варианта:

```
a = ["тест" , "услуга2" , "задание" , "услуга4" , "тест5" , "тест6" , "тест7" , "услуга8" , "группа"]
b = ["тест6" , "услуга2" , "услуга4" , "услуга8"]

for i in a:
    if i in b:
        print(1)
    else:
        print(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно исправить одну строчку

```
a = ["тест" , "услуга2" , "задание" , "услуга4" , "тест5" , "тест6" , "тест7" , "услуга8" , "группа"]
b = ["тест6" , "услуга2" , "услуга4" , "услуга8"]

common = list(set(a) & set(b))

for i in a:
    if i in common:
        print(1)
    else:
        print(0)
```